# OAuth2 with WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth2 into my applications for security and am getting stuck in the process.

I have been following a guide online:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH

But when i implement the code i am getting an error. The error seems to come when creating a 'Web Request' to the WCF Service. (*See Below*)

[image]

I was just wondering are other people experiencing this? If so, how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`(400) Bad Request` usually means your URI is incorrect. Please check whether your URI is correct or not.